# PlatformException(TRIGGER_ERROR, no se puede desencadenar el evento client-my-tracking porque el canal private-ride-138 está en estado SUBSCRIBE_SENT

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, pusher

I am making a delivery application in which the delivery man must constantly broadcast his location, everything is fine until the delivery man goes through areas where he does not have a very good signal for mobile data and pusher stops sending events, for which I have this error:

`PlatformException(TRIGGER_ERROR, Cannot trigger event client-my-tracking because channel private-ride-138 is in SUBSCRIBE_SENT state, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot trigger event client-my-tracking because channel private-ride-138 is in SUBSCRIBE_SENT state at com.pusher.client.channel.impl.PrivateChannelImpl.trigger(PrivateChannelImpl.java:48) at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService.trigger(PusherService.kt:278) at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService.access$trigger(PusherService.kt:30) at com.github.chinloyal.pusher_client.pusher.PusherService$register$1.onMethodCall(PusherService.kt:60) at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:178) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$handleMessageFromDart$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:206) at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$6ZD`

My question here is... how can I know the status of a channel? because in the documentation it only shows how to know the state of the pusher with `pusher.onConnectionStateChange()`, but this takes about 30 to 40 seconds to show in an emulator, or how can I know if my events are being sent correctly?

For example, I have this: when the distributor starts to move, I capture its location every 10 meters, which is why I ask about the connection status of the pusher:

````
await pusher.connect();
channel = pusher.subscribe('private-ride-$userId')
pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) async {
          pusherConnection = state?.currentState ?? 'DISCONNECTED';
          print(
              "--- CAMBIO DE ESTADO de:  ${state?.previousState} a -> ${state?.currentState}");

          if (state?.currentState == 'CONNECTED') {
            canSendEvents = true;
          } else {
            canSendEvents = false;
          }
        });
}

-- into other method:

BackgroundLocation.getLocationUpdates((position) async {
      final positionRepartidor = {
        "latitude": position.latitude,
        "longitude": position.longitude
      };
      if (canSendEvents) {
        channel.trigger('client-my-tracking', jsonEncode(positionRepartidor));
      } else {
        print("No envio nada porque el pusher está desconectado");
      }
    });

---and this one is my Pusher options configuration:
PusherClient pusher = PusherClient(
      Enviroments.appKeyPusher,
      PusherOptions(
          cluster: 'us2',
          encrypted: true,
          auth: PusherAuth(Enviroments.authEndPointPusher)),
      autoConnect: false);```

what should be the correct way to check the status of the channel, the pusher and the correct sending of events?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to [connection state](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/connection/#connection-states) changes but as you said it won't be real-time.

The best thing to do is to catch exceptions when you want to trigger an event. If the initial connection was successful, but the client could not trigger an event, it can be assumed that this is some kind of connection problem.

The best thing to do in that scenario depends on what you expect. If the whole trip is not important to you, you can ignore failed location updates because customers care about the last location.

If you care about the whole trip (for example, you are building a management dashboard to see if the deliverer is following the route correctly) you should save them in memory and try again later. (Probably you want to have a limit to control memory usage just in case the device goes offline for a very long period)